# Uppercase characters of a String

Tags: c++

The following code is supposed to make the first character uppercase, as well as any other occurrences of that same character.

For example, if the input is "complication", the output should be "CompliCation". But the output is "Complication" instead.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string cadena;

    std::cout << "Write a word: ";
    std::cin >> word;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (word[0] == word[i])
            word[i] = std::toupper(word[i]);
    }

    std::cout << word<< '\n';
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: After you capitalize the first letter you would only every execute your if statement on the same capital letter.  You need to store the first letter and then compare that to the string.

Comment: You already changed the first character to uppercase, `'C'  != 'c'`.

Comment: Because you changed `complication` to `Complication` when `i = 0`, so when you got to the next `c`, `Cadena[0] == Cadena[i]` was false.

Comment: i wonder why the close votes. Because the answer is obvious? Not obvious to the questioner.

Comment: Usually it helps to better understand what happens when you inspect the content of the variables during operation. Learn to use a debugger or excess use of print statements to solve such problems in the future on your own.

Comment: I'm looking at a question at -3. The rep of the answers is +100k. What gives?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: The answer was poorly written. (It's since been edited.) But a few people were able to understand what was being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you compare the second `c`, the first `c` has been converted to `C`. Hence, `Cadena[0] == Cadena[i]` is `false`.

Store the first character first and then compare it with the characters of the string.

```
char c = Cadena[0];
for (i = 0; i < Cadena.length(); i++)
{
   if (c == Cadena[i])
      Cadena[i] = toupper(Cadena[i]);
}
```

You can even pre-compute the uppercase character and use it in the loop.

```
char c = Cadena[0];
char upperC = toupper(c);
for (i = 0; i < Cadena.length(); i++)
{
   if (c == Cadena[i])
      Cadena[i] = upperC;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you make the first character upper case, so the 7th character does not match any more.

Modify your loop like this instead.

```
char c = Cadena[0];
for (i = 0; i < Cadena.length(); i++)
{
    if (Cadena[i] == c)
        Cadena[i] = toupper(Cadena[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because once you apply `toupper` on the very first character it becomes upper case. Then when it is compared with the same character but lowcase, the comparison returns `false`. Because 'C' is not the same as 'c'.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, i understand your example.

Answer (score 1):

After the first loop `Cadena[0] = 'C'` so when you encounter another occurrence of this letter, you do the test : `if ('C' == 'c')` which results to false.

You should first capitalize the characters that are the same to the first character (start your loop at `i=1`), then capitalize the first character after your `for` loop.